# In a dataframe with both positive & negative numbers, how to round positive numbers up and round negative numbers down (both to multiples of 5)?

Tags: python

With a dataframe as such:

```
data={'A1':[-7.22,-9.432,-0.00111,0.233,17,23,34],
      'A2':[-23,-7.2455,-0.00222,0.54,1.345,19,21]}
kk=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
         A1        A2
0  -7.22000 -23.00000
1  -9.43200  -7.24550
2  -0.00111  -0.00222
3   0.23300   0.54000
4  17.00000   1.34500
5  23.00000  19.00000
6  34.00000  21.00000
```

I want to round positive numbers up but negative numbers down (in multiples of 5), for example:

- 21 will become 25 instead of 20
- -7 will become -10 instead of -5

Tried using this method only to receive an error

```
def roundupdown5(x):
   if x>=0:
       return np.ceil(x/5)*5
   else:
       return np.floor(x/5)*5

kk[['A1','A2']].apply(lambda x: roundupdown5(x))
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not useful to tell us "... only to receive an error". Error messages have all of that text in them for a reason. [Please show it to us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146), by copying and pasting, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`, and formatting it like code (see the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: That said: the error from this code occurs because `.apply` will pass an entire column (`Series` object) to `roundupdown5` each time, rather than an individual cell value. `.apply` is intended for processing each column (or each row), not each cell. For that, you want `.applymap`. This is explained [in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Comment: `apply`/`applymap` should really be avoided as this would be quite slow on large DataFrames, here it is straightforward to use a vectorial approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) instead of `apply()`

```
kk.applymap(roundupdown5)
```

results in

```
      A1    A2
0   -10.0   -25.0
1   -10.0   -10.0
2   -5.0    -5.0
3   5.0 5.0
4   20.0    5.0
5   25.0    20.0
6   35.0    25.0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use dict and list comprehension to apply the `roundupdown5()` function to all the values of `data` before building the `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data={'A1':[-7.22,-9.432,-0.00111,0.233,17,23,34],'A2':[-23,-7.2455,-0.00222,0.54,1.345,19,21]}
kk=pd.DataFrame(data)


def roundupdown5(x):
    if x>=0:
        return np.ceil(x/5)*5
    else:
        return np.floor(x/5)*5

data = {k:[roundupdown5(i) for i in v] for k, v in data.items()}
kk=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data, kk)
```

**Output:**

```
{'A1': [-10.0, -10.0, -5.0, 5.0, 20.0, 25.0, 35.0], 'A2': [-25.0, -10.0, -5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 20.0, 25.0]}      A1    A2
0 -10.0 -25.0
1 -10.0 -10.0
2  -5.0  -5.0
3   5.0   5.0
4  20.0   5.0
5  25.0  20.0
6  35.0  25.0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`numpy.ceil`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.htm) on the absolute values and bring back the sign with [`numpy.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.htm), then you benefit from vectorial speed:

```
np.ceil(abs(kk)/5)*5*np.sign(kk)
```

output:

```
     A1    A2
0 -10.0 -25.0
1 -10.0 -10.0
2  -5.0  -5.0
3   5.0   5.0
4  20.0   5.0
5  25.0  20.0
6  35.0  25.0
```

Comment: anything incorrect in my answer?